# MVC 3 Not Recognizing Windows Role (Group)?

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

Has anybody come across occurrences where MVC does not recognize roles from Windows? I thought that roles translated to groups in Windows, but for some reason when I add a user to a group, check in MVC (using windows authentication) if that user.IsInRole("GroupJustAddedTo") always returns false. I have no idea why....Working in Server 2003 R2 with Windows Authentication enabled around the board. Confused :~( ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything else, it makes me wonder if perhaps your MVC is not really connected to your AD server.  Also, perhaps the user that is fetching the groups doesn't have sufficient privileges?  Just some initial thoughts.

**EDIT**

We ended up writing our own RoleProvider.  Here is the overloaded GetRolesForUser code

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userName)
{
    List<string> allRoles = new List<string>();
    PrincipalContext context;
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "hlpusd.k12.ca.us", "DC=hlpusd,DC=k12,DC=ca,DC=us");
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);
    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> usergroups = user.GetGroups(); // list of AD groups the user is member of
    IEnumerator<Principal> eGroup = usergroups.GetEnumerator();
    while (eGroup.MoveNext())
    {
        allRoles.Add(eGroup.Current.Name);
    }

    return allRoles.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I don't understand. I believe it's connected to AD because it has no problem authenticating a windows user.

Comment: Then it would appear your problem lies somewhere in your role discovery.  Are you perhaps swallowing an exception?  I've got all my MVC apps hooked up using the MembershipRoleProvider and the only time I have problems is either when I write it wrong or there is a permissions problem.  Other than that, it just works.

Comment: What steps do you take to ensure permissions are correct? Are there specific users you add to specific groups? Im using windows authentication, so I don't know if your scenario is comparable.....

Comment: When you say Windows Authentication, what do you mean by that?  Is that in IIS?  When someone authenticates against that, doesn't it hit your Active Directory server?  That is the only kind of Windows Authentication I know of, but I want to make sure that is what we're talking about.

Comment: Yes, it should be interacting with my local groups and active directory.  I setup the entire App with default setting for an Intranet application.  From what I have been told, I should have no problem getting information to and from active directory and the local user/groups from the server...

Comment: I'm remembering that we ended up overloading some of the RoleProvider methods to get the groups.  I've included our code in this answer.